# how to validate a many fields in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

In my windows application i have a tab control with many tabs and sub tab controls also, each and every tab has many field like text boxes and list boxes.
i thought to validate every field by clicking button called "NEXT" before changing to nexttab and if any field fails with validation a message box should pop-up with error message and  focus should remain in that field. can any one help me with ur suggestions...

validation requirements are required field and only numeric and alphanumeric...

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: What have you done so far? You can iterate through the form controls and subcontrols and validate based on your criteria.

Comment: seems rather simple, on the next button action you verify each field if 1 fails you set the focus event to the field and return, you can also disable the next tabs until the validation requirement is met. **What have you done so far and what does not work for ?**

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to create a derived controls with input area and validation logic. Then, it is matter of enumerating hierarchy of controls and see if they are valid based on validation rules applied.

Another way, is to "attach" validation logic to controls. How? A mapping mechanism or use the "Tag" property.

But isn't it better to validate control using "Validate" event, when user tries to exit the control? That will not allow user to supply bunch of trash and hope it can be saved.

Comment: validating right in `Validated` or `Validating` event handlers are OK, however that's not always the case which we should do follow.